# Python 2.7: how to pass options for standalone/module code

Tags: python, python-2.7, default-value, argparse

I have written a python module mymod.py that can be used also as a standalone program from command line.

In mymod.py I have defined a few functions (where default values are set using keywords)
and an `if __name__=="__main__"` block to use the module as a standalone program.

I want the possibility to override some of the default options, therefore in the main program I `import argparse` and use it to parse the options. I use a dictionary to store
the default values, so that if some day I need to change the default values I can easily 
do it modifying its value in one place only.

It works, but I find that the code is not "clean" and thought that probably I am not doing it in the proper pythonic way.

This is a toy example to show what I do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#mymod.py

__default_options__={
  "f1_x":10,
  "f2_x":10
}

def f1(x=__default_options__["f1_x"]):
  return x**2

def f2(x=__default_options__["f2_x"]):
  return x**4

# this function is the "core" function which uses f1 and f2 
# to produce the main task of the program
def f(x=__default_options__["f1_x"],y=__default_options__["f2_x"]):
  return f1(x)+f2(y)

if __name__=="__main__":
  import argparse
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "A toy application")
  parser.add_argument("--f1-x",help="the parameter passed to f1",
    default=__default_options__["f1_x"], type = float,dest = "x")  
   parser.add_argument("--f2-x",help="the parameter passed to f2",
     default=__default_options__["f2_x"], type = float, dest = "y")

  options= parser.parse_args()
  print f(options.x,options.y)
```

Passing the default values like I do it is a bit cumbersome and probably against the spirit both of Python and argparse.

How can this code be improved to be more pythonic and use argparse at its best?

Comment: I think, that you should not use variables with two underscores, since it might break code in future python versions.

Comment: Besides, the arguments in a functions are evaluated at definition time, not when the function is called. So if you change `__default_options__` at run time, the default for `f1`, `f2` and `f` will not change (this might or might not be what you want)

Comment: I used the underscore because I want the user not to change the default options.. If they want to override the values they have to call the function like f(x=3) for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ArgumentParser.set_defaults](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.set_defaults) method, in the following way

```
default_options={
    "x":10,
    "y":10
}

def f1(**kwargs):
    x=kwargs.get('x', defalut_options['x'])
    return x**2

def f2(**kwargs):
    y=kwargs.get('y', defalut_options['y'])
    return x**4

def f(**kwargs):
    x=kwargs.get('x', defalut_options['x'])
    y=kwargs.get('y', defalut_options['y'])
    return f1(x=x, y=y)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "A toy application", formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter )
    parser.add_argument("--f1-x",help="the parameter passed to f1",
      type = float,dest = "x")
    parser.add_argument("--f2-x",help="the parameter passed to f2",
      type = float, dest = "y")

    parser.set_defaults(**default_options)

    options= parser.parse_args()
    print f(options.x,options.y)
```

It took me a while to make it work, because I didn't notice that you are using `dest` in `add_argument` (I never use it). If this keyword is not provided, argparse set the default `dest` to the long name of the argument (in this case `f1_x` and `f2_x`, as it substitutes `-` with `_`). To go to the point: if you want to provide a dictionary of defaults, the keys needs to match `dest` if provided. Besides, take care that `parser.set_defaults` just add arguments to the parser, so if you have some entry not in your parser, it will be added to the `Namespace`.

--Edited to add generic `kwargs` to the functions--

Comment: I didn't know the set_default methods, thanks.. 
but I still have to define a "global" dictionary (that contains default values for all the functions, which seems bad practice to me).. Maybe using groups helps?

Comment: I don't think that is a bad practice to set defaults using a dictionary. If the defaults for the functions are more that the defaults for `argparse` you can create a dict for the latter and copy and/or extend it for the functions.

Comment: OK, but I think that there is still some flaws in the way I use this.. In the toy example the functions have only one argument.. but it might be the case that I have more (since the "core" function uses many functions). Rather than writing them individually (and maybe forgot one..), isn't there a way to call f like f(**options_f1, **options_f2) [hope you get the sense] possibly making so that name clashes are avoided?

Comment: it's enough if you do `f(**kwargs)` and then in the function do something like this `var1 = kwargs.get('var1', default_options['var1')`. I've edited my aswer

Comment: `f(**options_f1, **options_f2)` throws you an error. You can do as in my edited answer, although might be that you must call the functions with `x=` or `y=`

Comment: thanks, just a few comment out of curiosity, if I want to use the x=None approach explained by alexis, should include a if x==None statement for each variable in all the functions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26733/discussion-between-francesco-montesano-and-luca-cerone)

Answer (score 1):

As @Francesco wrote in a comment, your defaults dictionary won't work as you probably intended: The functions will retain the defaults they had while loading the module, regardless of later changes to the dictionary. Here's how to make them track the current value of the dictionary:

```
_default_options = {
    "f1_x":10,
    "f2_x":10
}

def f1(x=None):
    if x == None:
        x = _default_options["f1_x"]
    ...
```

You can then modify `_default_options` via `ArgumentParser`, or in any other way, and `f1()` will use it if called with no arguments.

This requires that `None` could never be a meaningful value for `x`; if that's not the case, choose a suitable impossible value.

Comment: thanks for explaining my comment. I think that the question is about the best way to set defaults in `argparse`, not in function arguments.

Comment: As explained in a previous comment I don't plan the users to be able to change the default values..
What I wasn't expecting is that f1 can access _default_options event though that is not a global variable?

Comment: You can access global variables without declaring them `global`. The `global` is only necessary if you're going to modify them.